# Prove clique exists under the following conditions

Tags: graph-theory

> Given a graph $G$ with $n \ge 4$ vertices, where $n$ is even, prove that if every vertex has degree $n/2 + 1$, then $G$ must contain a clique of size $3$.

Recall that a *clique of size $3$* is cycle on $3$ vertices. Therefore, you must show that there always exists $3$ vertices $a, b, c$ in $G$ such that $ab$ is an edge, $bc$ is an edge and $ac$ is an edge.

Comment: The tag [proof-verification] is not relevant here because you have not supplied your own proof.